# Create Combo Chart (Bar with Candlestick) in Sheet using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am trying to create a combo chart in sheet embedded script. The chart needs to have a combination of Bar Chart and Candlestick Chart.

I am able to create a similar chart on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abdullah_swgapps/3o81Lbhv/26/) using Google Charts JS library.

But when I try a similar approach on Apps Script, I get a Bar Chart with Line Chart.

My current code and the result are given below:

```
var chart = chartSheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.COMBO)
  .addRange(range)
  .setPosition(25, 8, 0, 0)
  .setOption('seriesType', 'candlesticks')
  .setOption('series', {1: {type: 'bars'}})
  .build()
```

[image: chart screenshot]

This is the dataset I am using (screenshot from spreadsheet):

[image: sheet structure screenshot]

Comment: does it matter that in the code above, you set series __1__ to bars, whereas in the fiddle you set series __0__ to bars?

Comment: @WhiteHat thank you for the comment. Setting it to 0 just shows 1 bar and 3 lines. But does not show the candlestick chart.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a combo EmbeddedChart that contains a candlestick can be created with Apps Script. Have you considered reporting this in Issue Tracker?